# Title name of my new card changes all the other cards' name to the new title name

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, setstate

I have a listview which displays cards on but whenever I add a new card, the title of all the cards is updated to the new title but I need just the current added one to change

```dart
final taskName = TextEditingController();

 TextField(
                  controller: taskName,
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(hintText: 'Task Name'),
                ),
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                children: [
                  ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      counter++;
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                    },
                    child: const Text(
                      'Add',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
                    ),
                  ),

Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: counter,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) {
                  return TodoContainer(
                    cardTitle: taskName.text.toString(),
                  );
                }),
          )
```

**ScreenShot to show how my cards look like after adding a new card with name of TODO**

[image: ScreenShot to show how my cards look like after adding a new card with name of TODO]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a single `TextEditingController` value to populate the `ListView`, therefore listview children is getting update value instead of creating new item.

`final taskName = TextEditingController();`

What you can do, create a list of String and feed it on children.

```dart
  List<String> items = []; // on state class

 .... 
 // add data 
  onPressed: () {
    items.add(taskName.text.toString()); 
     ....
      },

......

/// populate listView
 return TodoContainer(
         cardTitle: items[index],
             );
```

Comment: WOW you're awesome..Thank you very much. You have always been helpimg me whenever I am stuck

Comment: glad to help you out, you can check [sample apps](https://flutter.github.io/samples/#)